# Mac is draining battery way too quickly, especially when it's off

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, battery

This morning, my mac was at 90-ish% battery, but after closing it for about an hour, it drained all the way to 30%. My mac battery isn't the greatest, but it drains slower when it's on than when it's off now. The only app running was Chrome, and although I do have a lot of tabs open on it, the vast majority of them are inactive. It was very warm when I held it and the fan was on.

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: there are many settings and apps that can do that

Comment: There is no way a laptop that is off drains battery faster than a laptop that is on.  If it is warm to the touch when you believe it’s off, it is running and doing this will undoubtedly drain your battery. Next time try closing Chrome before you turn off/put to sleep the laptop and see if it has any effect

Comment: Actually "off", e.g. shutdown? Or just sleeping? How old is the Mac? How many battery cycles?  I would test if not using Chrome is any better. (Better for your security, certainly, if not battery life.)

Answer (score 0):

ahh the Vampire or the Insomnia mode.

It waits for you to go to sleep then it ravages around.

User friendly method.

In Activity Monitor look for "Preventing Sleep".

> How to >>Right click on the menu bar and select preventing sleep that will show you a new coulomb with who is preventing sleep.

In System preferences select battery or Power saver and disable all

Look deeper:

In Terminal use `pmset -g assertions`

If you do not know what you are looking at, publish the screen shots here so we can help

Comment: The first `>>` seems to have been interpreted as a double block-quote - I'm not sure if that was intentional. If not, then this character, ►, *might* be better..?